# How to fix DateTimeNormalizer issue when using Symfony Serializer

Tags: symfony, serialization

I am having trouble using the Symfony Serializer to normalize DateTime objects into strings.

I am using the following code:

```
protected function createResponse($data, Int $statusCode){

    $serializedData = $this->serialize($data);

    return new Response($serializedData, $statusCode, array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ));

}

protected function serialize($data, string $format = 'json')
{
    $encoders = [new JsonEncoder()];
    $normalizers = [new ObjectNormalizer(), new DateTimeNormalizer()];

    $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

    return $serializer->serialize($data, $format);
}
```

I am passing Entities which contain DateTimeInterface variables into the createResponse method defined above but the dates are not being normalised to the RFC3339 format. Am I missing an important step?

Example output I am getting:

```
"reportDate":{"timezone":{"name":"UTC","transitions":[{"ts":-9223372036854775808,"time":"-292277022657-01-27T08:29:52+0000","offset":0,"isdst":false,"abbr":"UTC"}],"location":{"country_code":"??","latitude":0,"longitude":0,"comments":""}},"offset":0,"timestamp":1551398400}
```

Comment: Did you try moving the dateTimeNormalizer before the object normalizer?

Comment: I just tried emix and it works thank you so much!

Comment: Please mark my answer as the solution then. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**tl;dr** order matters.

Try:

```
$normalizers = [new DateTimeNormalizer(), new ObjectNormalizer()];
```

Instead of:

```
$normalizers = [new ObjectNormalizer(), new DateTimeNormalizer()];
```

Comment: Could you explain on why this exactly solves the problem? Because it seems that the order of the normalizers is something that apparently matters but it does not seem to be documented.